# Nodemon app cannot find module when restarting

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I'm currently building a RESTful API. I start my MongoDB server using the command `mongod`. When I restart my Node server (using `rs`), however, it throws the following error:

```
[nodemon] starting `node todoListApi`
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Zakaria5\Desktop\Stage Technique 
2019\zen-networks-backend\todoListApi'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I Googled this error, and the solution seemed to be to remove the `node_modules` directory. However, when I type `rm -rf nodes_modules`, it displays that the command is not found. I also tried using `npm install` and `npm start`, but this throws an error, as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Are you trying to remove `node_modules`, or `nodes_modules`?

Comment: @IronFlare in vain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve the problem by fixing the path !! Well , when i type npm install and npm start !  It displays an error which confirms that the file isnt available in a path by default !! (in my case) C/users/Zakaria/package.json !! when i look for that file i didnt find it ! Thus , I have to change the path which contains my package.json file . I used that command " npm start --prefix TheRealPath "  Hence , the RESTful API starts on port : 3000 !! :P